# How to convert the pdf files into png format using ghostscript in python

Tags: python, ghostscript

How to convert the pdf files in good quality with normal size?
I want to convert the pdf files into png format using ghostscript..in python..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code-->
Enter your pdf file name with directory

```
os.system("mkdir /.pdf")
```

In the following code you will get your images

```
s.system("gs -q -dSAFER  -sDEVICE=png16m -r500 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE  -dFirstPage=%d -dLastPage=%d -sOutputFile=/xx.png %s" %(i,i,self.id,i,pdfname))
```

Enter your pdf name and you will get the output as png format